# IllegalAnnotationExceptions There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

I got the following error while running the project on the command prompt with

```
java com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.main.Main
```

I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main"    com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {unison}FromTime.
    this problem is related to the following location:
            at protected java.util.List com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Test.dateOrStartDateOrEndDate
            at com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Test
            at protected java.util.List com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Condition.content
            at com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Condition
            at protected com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Condition com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Rule.condition
            at com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Rule
            at protected java.util.List com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Policy.rule
            at com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Policy
            at protected java.util.List com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Configuration.policyOrConditionOrActionList
            at com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Configuration
            at protected com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.Configuration com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.BMWebgateConf.configuration
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.main.Main.main(Main.java:55)
```

Source:
com/javavids/jaxb/sitemap/UPM/Test.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"conditionRef",
"attribute",
"op",
"dateOrStartDateOrEndDate",
"listRef",
"value"
 })
@XmlRootElement(name = "Test")

public class Test {

@XmlElement(name = "ConditionRef")
protected String conditionRef;
@XmlElement(name = "Attribute")
protected String attribute;
@XmlElement(name = "Op")
protected String op;
@XmlElementRefs({

    @XmlElementRef(name = "FromTime", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Date", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "DurationInDays", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "EndDate", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "StartDate", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "ToTime", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Weekday", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Frequency", namespace = "unison", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
})
protected List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> dateOrStartDateOrEndDate;
@XmlElement(name = "ListRef")
protected String listRef;
@XmlElement(name = "Value")
protected String value;
@XmlAttribute(name = "Type", required = true)
protected String type;


 public List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> getDateOrStartDateOrEndDate() {
    if (dateOrStartDateOrEndDate == null) {
        dateOrStartDateOrEndDate = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>>();
    }
    return this.dateOrStartDateOrEndDate;
}
```

Source:
com/javavids/jaxb/sitemap/UPM/ObjectFactory.java

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

private final static QName _StartDate_QNAME = new QName("unison", "StartDate");    
private final static QName _Date_QNAME = new QName("unison", "Date");
private final static QName _ToTime_QNAME = new QName("unison", "ToTime");
private final static QName _CreateTime_QNAME = new QName("unison", "CreateTime");
private final static QName _EndDate_QNAME = new QName("unison", "EndDate");
private final static QName _FromTime_QNAME = new QName("unison", "FromTime");
private final static QName _DurationInDays_QNAME = new QName("unison", "DurationInDays");
private final static QName _ImportTime_QNAME = new QName("unison", "ImportTime");
private final static QName _Frequency_QNAME = new QName("unison", "Frequency");
private final static QName _Weekday_QNAME = new QName("unison", "Weekday");

@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "unison", name = "StartDate")
public JAXBElement<String> createStartDate(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_StartDate_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}

@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "unison", name = "FromTime")
public JAXBElement<String> createFromTime(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_FromTime_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
}
```

Source: 
com/javavids/jaxb/sitemap/main/Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\t_pavans\\workspace\\jaxbTest1\\medialossy.xml");

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap.UPM.BMWebgateConf.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    //BMWebgate Root element variables
    bmw = (BMWebgateConf) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

NOTE: The code work completely fine on my Eclipse. But when I try to run on command prompt, it throws and exception

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When create the `JAXBContext` from classes you need to include the `ObjectFactory` class in the classes passed in to create the `JAXBContext`.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BMWebgateConf.class, ObjectFactory.class);
```

If your model is generated from an XML schema then I would recommend creating the `JAXBContext` on the package name:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.javavids.jaxb.sitemap");
```

Comment: This is a savior! Saved my day.. I added multiple ObjectFactory classes which came from different packages. Thanksss