# There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase}footnoteLink

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

Hi when i wanna create xml from java object with jaxb i'm getting this error message,

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase}footnoteLink.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected java.util.List org.xbrl._2003.instance.Xbrl.itemOrTupleOrContext
>           at org.xbrl._2003.instance.Xbrl
>           at protected org.xbrl._2003.instance.Xbrl tr.gov.edefter.Berat.xbrl
>           at tr.gov.edefter.Berat
>           at public tr.gov.edefter.Berat tr.gov.edefter.ObjectFactory.createBerat()
>           at tr.gov.edefter.ObjectFactory

Here is my code,

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
    try {       
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("tr.gov.edefter");
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE); // To format XML
        // Print XML String to Console
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(defter, System.out);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have to finish this project in a few weeks 
Thanks any for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalAnnotationExceptions There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818117/illegalannotationexceptions-theres-no-objectfactory-with-an-xmlelementdecl-for)

Comment: I tried this but same problem. I handle this way with another class there is no problem. But this time i cant handle it. Maybe there is different way to create xml from java object i dont know

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final Class<?>[] FILING_TYPES = new Class[] {
    Defter.class,
    Xbrl.class,
    org.xbrl._2003.linkbase.Linkbase.class,
    org.xbrl._2003.instance.ObjectFactory.class,
    org.xbrl._2003.linkbase.FootnoteLink.class,
 };

 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FILING_TYPES);
```

it works.

but when set *Xbrl itemOrTupleOrContext* has *java.util.ArrayList* nor any of its super class is known to this context problem